# How to use own swagger-ui with Liberty JSON generated content

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, websphere-liberty, swagger-2.0

There is an internal Liberty swagger-ui and it is working fine for me, but actually we need to make our own swagger layout, I mean putting our logo and our company name ... etc.

**This is what we get when calling *https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/docs* with basic swagger-ui**
[image]

But when we use the browser url and paste **https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/docs** we got the json content for our services

**This is how it working with ibm liberty swagger-ui**
[image]

**And this how we need to show it to our clients**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to alter the "look & feel" of the built-in Liberty Swagger UI, but there is a Request For Enhancement that you can vote for: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=87860

If you want to have your own Swagger UI totally independent of Liberty's UI, you can still pull from /ibm/api/docs like your first screenshot showed - the only thing you're missing is to setup CORS support on that Liberty instance, so that your custom Swagger UI is allowed to call it.

Here's the doc for setting up CORS in Liberty: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_webcontainer_cors_config.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-8-1-1-21-1

Main sample from the link:

```
<cors domain="/ibm/api/collective"
  allowedOrigins="https://alice.com:8090"
  allowedMethods="GET, DELETE, POST"
  allowedHeaders="accept, MyRequestHeader1"
  exposeHeaders="MyResponseHeader1"
  allowCredentials="true"
  maxAge="3600" />
```

Comment: Actually i am already using this tag(cors), and i got the error when i used it, so this not helped me at all, it was mean for me that cors tag is not working at all and i don't know why

Comment: BTW, this is what i am using in server.xml 

<cors allowCredentials="true" allowedHeaders="Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, Authorization" allowedMethods="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" allowedOrigins="http://localhost:9080" domain="/ibm/api/docs" exposeHeaders="Content-Type" maxAge="3600"/>


 <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>


 <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}EzY9Oi0rJg=="/>


 <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="ibm/api">
  <user name="skios" password="{xor}LDQ2MCwvKDs="/> 
 </basicRegistry>